# javafx treeview css how to add line after every parent node

Tags: javafx, treeview, javafx-2

In JavaFx treeView, how to add line after every parent node ? Please refer to my code below. I tried to select only child node in css and apply border with top transparent and select only parent node and apply border with bottom transparent.

```
.tree-view .tree-cell {
   -fx-indent: 0;
 }
 .tree-cell:filled:selected {
   -fx-border-color: transparent #111111 #111111 #111111;
   -fx-background-color: rgb(100,100,100,0.2);
  }
 .tree-cell:hover .highlight-on-hover { /* not working, this is where I need some help */
   -fx-border-color: transparent #111111 #111111 #111111;
   -fx-background-color: rgb(100,100,100,0.2);
  }
```

This is causing a line in between my parent and child node which I want to eliminate. How to do that ?

Comment: Do you have a specific `TreeItem` structure? In general, any `TreeItem` is both a parent and a child.

Comment: Yes @James_D, because of this reason, I have to drop entire idea of using a tree-view as a replacement for custom accordion.